# Missing first record DAO access

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I have this code:

```
If Len(Me.Text9.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
      sSQL = "SELECT [Ra 1080] as [civil] FROM civil where main=" & Forms![PDS Main Form]![Main Table ID] & " ORDER BY ID"
      Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
      rs.MoveFirst
           Do Until rs.EOF
              Text9.Value = Text9.Value + rs!civil + ", "
           rs.MoveNext
           Loop
           Set rs = Nothing
           End If
```

If you run the query it would return 3 records cs1.5,cs1.3,cs1.9

running  the code the textbox would only return cs 1.3, cs 1.9,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure using MoveFirst would have caused the trouble, try this code. See if it works.

```
If Len(Me.Text9.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    sSQL = "SELECT [Ra 1080] As [civil] FROM civil WHERE main = " & _
            Forms![PDS Main Form]![Main Table ID] & " ORDER BY ID"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Text9.Value = Text9.Value & rs!civil & ", "
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

Just taken away the .MoveFirst and few other simple modifications.